# Search - will it index apps, iframes, for example for People Search?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Just to check.  With the app model, does the indexer/crawler correctly index client-side generated data as well as looking in iframes?

The recommended way forward from MS seems to be to use those two - but means the crawler would have to run page Javascript for content to appear and look in iframes (app parts).  I would hope that it does, can anyone confirm?